# launch mstsc.exe with pekts00.rdp configured on enable

Tags: c#, rdp

I am adding security to one of my application. I would like that on Enable, C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe c:\thinclient\pekts00.rdp with .rdp (remote desktop) configured is launched. It will continue to run to check if mstsc.exe is running and will logoff windows or start it if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below... It will help you...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] pname = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc");
if (pname.Length == 0)
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\system32\mstsc.exe");
```

Comment: +0 so far - you are missing a way to specify RDP file and please show correct way (%windir%) to specify path to mstsc.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: i have edited my code... is this you except..?

Comment: yes it helps thank you... I don't want to kill the process if it is running though, I just want to make sure it is ALWAYS running

Comment: @DrewSalesse: Thanks, If it helps you then mark it as answer,  Then only it was easily identify to Others..

Comment: I need to launch to  c:\thinclient\pekts00.rdp

Comment: @DrewSalesse: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\thinclient\pekts00.rdp");` Try like this... it will launch the application

Comment: +1. Also actual sample still missing specifying parameters to the application, your last comment provides a way to solve it.